# How can I add an if statement to jquery drag and drop?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm using [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) drag and drop and it works fine. What would be the syntax to use so I can add an if statement? i.e so I can only drag and drop my divisions when a global variable reaches a certain number. I was able to easily add that when using javascript drag and drop but have to yet to figure out how with jquery drag and drop. There's a [plugin](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to make jquery drag work on touch screen devices which is why I'm switching over.

(Yes I'm new to both javascript and jquery!)

Thanks for any help.

Here's the code:

```
$( "#div1" ).draggable();

$( "#div3" ).droppable();
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/ you will probably hook on some callback drag, start, stop. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look down that list. I mean I only want the division to be dragable after a different object is finished animating. So when var myAnimNumber = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible, Here you go http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#events

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
    if(432423423 > 1 ){
       //hello world you just activated 
    }
  }
});
```